# rails image_tag not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, google-chrome

UPDATE: does anyone know why the images show up in Firefox but not in Chrome?

I just tested my app in Firefox and the images show up! But they do not show up in Google Chrome. Does anyone know why this is?

Original question posted to Ruby-on-Rails and Ruby..below line

---

Ok, so I'm having hell with the image_tag in rails. I have the following code in my index.html.erb

code in..

```
<% @most_recent_tweets.each do |tweet| %>
    <%= image_tag (tweet["user"]["profile_image_url"]) %>
<% end %>
```

The following is what appears on the actual webpage

code out..

```
<img alt="Eli_face_1_bigger_normal" src="http://a2.twimg.com/profile_images/498988018/eli_face_1_bigger_normal.jpg">
```

The html for the image shows up in the code but no image displays in the browser. Why is this? Any ideas?

Comment: It's working here: http://jsbin.com/efiwiz Something else is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding .html_safe

image_tag (tweet["user"]["profile_image_url"]).html_safe

Comment: Hmm still no go strange and I just tested it in Firefox and the images show up! More strange.